Flutter, cubit, How to notify local instances of many of the same object, cubit state, that they disappeared from view and then reappeared?
I`m using Widget
class FilterIconButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final CloudListWidgetData cloudListWidgetData;
  final cloud.CloudListDetails cloudListDetails;
  final String filterId;

  FilterIconButton({
    @required this.cloudListWidgetData,
    @required this.cloudListDetails,
    Key key,
  })  : filterId = Uuid().v4(),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterIconButton> createState() => _FilterIconButtonState();
}

class _FilterIconButtonState extends State<FilterIconButton> {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final isFiltered = context.read<FilterIconCubit>().state.filterState;
    if (isFiltered) {
      BlocProvider.of<FilterDataCubit>(context).clearFilterList();
      context.read<FilterIconCubit>().showFilterOnIcon();
    } else {
      context.read<FilterIconCubit>().showFilterOffIcon();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<FilterIconCubit, FilterIconState>(
      builder: (context, iconState) {
        final isFiltered = iconState.filterState;
        return isFiltered
            ? IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.filter_alt_off_outlined,
            color: Properties.appColors.BRAND_PRIMARY,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            BlocProvider.of<FilterDataCubit>(context).clearFilterList();
            context.read<FilterIconCubit>().showFilterOffIcon();
          },
        )
            : IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.filter_alt_outlined,
            color: Properties.appColors.BRAND_PRIMARY,
          ),
          onPressed: () => _showFilterListDialog(context),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showFilterListDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => FilterListDialogWidget(
        cloudListWidgetData: widget.cloudListWidgetData,
        cloudListDetails: widget.cloudListDetails,
      ),
    ).then((value) {
      if (value == true) {
        context.read<FilterIconCubit>().showFilterOnIcon();
      } else {
        context.read<FilterIconCubit>().showFilterOffIcon();
      }
    });
  }
}

I have a FilterIconButton widget in my Flutter application that sometimes appears multiple times on the same screen or in different tabs. I need to reset its icon state back to Icons.filter_alt_outlined when changing tabs. Additionally, I’m unsure if the BlocProvider(create: (context) => FilterIconCubit()) in my main.dart file is correctly scoped, or if it should be provided where the object is used.
How can I notify the FilterIconButton to change the icon back to Icons.filter_alt_outlined when switching tabs?
Is the BlocProvider(create: (context) => FilterIconCubit()) in main.dart file correctly scoped, or should it be provided where the object is used?
P.S. I know that in React this is easy sorted  using rerender properly.

I believe I'd need to see the details of the FilterIconCubit to provide you an answer with more confidence, so that'd be my first question:
Is the FilterIconCubit meant to manage the state of one or many FilterIconButtons?
Depending on the scope of it's responsibility you would - as you suggest yourself - want to move the BlocProvider to be more closely tied to each instantiation of the FilterIconButton widget.
This makes each bloc responsible for the state of a single FilterIconButton.
Let me know if this helps, and otherwise, feel free to provide further details.
